# redirect not working, have to refresh page every time

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

*I am attempted to redirect in the post method every time i hit submit (which adds more "art" to the database) but I have to refresh afterwards to get the new entry to show up instead. I have included my main.py code and the html below. How can I fix this so I don't have to manually refresh after every submission. (this is from the udacity web development course).*

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                                autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Art(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    art = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class MainPage(Handler):
    def render_front(self, title="", art="", error=""):
        arts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Art order by created desc")
        self.render("front.html", title = title, art = art, error = error, arts = arts)

    def get(self):
        self.render_front()

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get("title")
        art = self.request.get("art")

        if title and art:
            a = Art(title=title, art=art)
            a.put()
            self.redirect("/")

        else:
            error = "we need both a title and some artwork!"
            self.render_front(error=error, title=title,art=art)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

html:

```
  <form method="post">
    <label>
      <div>title</div>
      <input type="text" name="title" value="{{title}}">
    </label>

    <label>
      <div>art</div>
      <textarea name="art">{{art}}</textarea>
    <label>

    <div class="error">{{error}}</div>

    <input type="submit">
  </form>

  <hr>

  {% for art in arts %}
    <div class="art">
      <div class="art-title">{{art.title}}</div>
      <pre class="art-body">{{art.art}}</pre>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirect is working fine.  The reason the new entity doesn't show up is because of [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) with the GAE datastore.  When you put an entity, it can take a little time before it is available to be queried.

There are workarounds, but they depend on the particular application.  For example, you can store a list of keys since getting by key will always work or you could use memcache.